# How to monitor query load, counts, and durations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, monitoring

I'd like to understand load (average active), count, and, average time of various queries.

This is an AWS RDS Performance Insights dashboard. This is the sort of information that I want, though as you can see, it's half broken. (Issue has been escalated to technical support, so likely I'll hear back in mid-November.)

Queries can get long, say up to a couple thousand characters.

Are there any good ways to get this usage/performance information? This would seem essential to improving real-world DB performance but so far I haven't turned up much.

[image]

Comment: You subscribe to a managed service, you get what you pay for. If you're ready to roll your own dashboards, there's [pg_stat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html)

Comment: You can use pg_stat_statements https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pgstatstatements.html extension in AWS RDS or check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html

Comment: "You subscribe to a managed service, you get what you pay for. " If only :/